# Обновление данных при возврате на предыдущую страницу через браузер

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, google-chrome, firefox

Возникла проблема, что браузер сильно кэширует страницы. По другому я это назвать не могу.
При возврате на предыдущую страницу через браузерную кнопку "назад", предыдущая страница не перезагружается, а возвращается в таком же состоянии, как и до перехода на следующую страницу.

Сайт динамичный и ему требуется обновление данных при возврате назад.

Как это можно исправить?

Актуально для Chrome и Firefox

**UPDATED**

Для лучшего понимания, распишу на примере

На первой странице имеется объект, который меняет свои значения от действий пользователя. После того, как пользователь перешел на вторую страницу, этот объект должен очищаться. Сразу поясню, что он очищается перед переходом.

Суть в том, что пользователь, нажав на браузерную кнопку назад и вернувшись на первую страницу, все равно видит неочищенный объект, хотя у него все в потерто.

Немного покопавшись стало понятно, что есть браузеры, которые сильно кэшируют все, и именно кэш видят пользователи.

Как это обойти?

Comment: нажать кнопку `f5`?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что именно не возвращается. Данные? Так вопрос в том как вы их подтягиваете и подтягиваете ли вообще. Нужен либо код либо больше деалей

Comment: Вам нужно копать в сторону HistoryAPI, по идее должны быть какие-то возможности сбрасывать состояние. Вот то, что может помочь (из EnSO): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572508, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044554

Comment: "Сайт динамичный и ему требуется обновление данных при возврате назад." - а какие данные-то не обновляются?! "возвращается в таком же состоянии" - это в каком?! "Это мелочь, мелочь. Но нет ничего важнее мелочей. От любой самой ничтожной мелочи можно протянуть цепь логических рассуждений." Шерлок Холмс.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.